# HTML Textarea Defualt text? (Like layout)

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want a default layout  user can use for textarea.
and not a placeholder...
sort of a pre-text type of thing. how would i approach this?
ive tried using DOM to add innerHTML and innerText, cant find 
anything on google so hopefully someone here can help.

for example

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9NeQ.png)

(This isnt a placeholder)
its a layout for user to go off.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you're trying to accomplish? Can you post any relevant examples?

Comment: check post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solution**

```
<textarea>
JUST

Put your text inside Textarea 

Which ever way you like


</textarea>
```

Comment: Also another easy fix, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the text of a `textarea` programmatically by accessing the `value` property.

For instance:

```
document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = "Some default text";
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, simple fix, much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark this as accepted if it solved your problem.